# Is running a light Ethereum node in a local server a good solution for not having to pay a 3rd party provider?

Tags: nodes

I've been looking into some providers for Ethereum blockchain data via web3 and the prices might get a little bit crazy. How feasible is to run light node in a local server to use it on my code instead of a (for instance) infura project? If I run a light mode, would I have access as well to characteristics like the mempool, historical transactions from old blocks, etc.?

From my total lack of understanding and from the little I've read so far it seems fairly easy to run a node, but what are some of the drawbacks or limitations in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there are no drawbacks, just a bit more time taking... get an old laptop, run a light node, use it how you want. You have mempool & tx query via other nodes.

I run nodes for all my clients in the cloud...even have ones that haven't been restarted in 2 years so it's pretty solid

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What confuses me is that if it's so easy to run a node, why would anyone pay +$2000 per month to be able to connect to a provider like infura with limited requests, when they can have a light node running for free with unlimited requests?

Comment: Where did you see $2000/month? All the node providers other than quicknode (infura, alchemy, moralis) have free (rate-limited) endpoints which are fine for most use cases. But even these free endpoints are often archival nodes. Running an archival node on aws can cost you north of $200/month just for the lowest quality EBS storage (requires >1TB storage).